# how to get page count in dompdf without using page text

Tags: php, dompdf

I want to get page count of my pdf without using page text.
I can get page count using page_text method. 
But I want to get without using page_text. 
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: please add code your already tried which might be giving you an error. please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we can provide better solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get page count using `get_page_count()` method.

```
$pdf->$get_canvas()->$get_page_count();
```

Thanks.